# Laradock expose nginx port

Tags: docker, nginx

I've been trying to expose nginx port to be able to access page with external ip.

I've tried to expose port 80 with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But nothing changed:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7008/docker-proxy
```

Laradock documentation isn't clear about this issue.

Also I found that you can expose port with command

```
docker run --expose=80 nginx
```

But it always says unable to find image and starts building it.

Comment: What line are you using to run your laradock container? Using the docker command you'd spin up a nginx container and expose port 80 of that particular container.

Comment: I run it with docker-compose up -d nginx mysql. Looking into options I do not see any --expose or anything related to ports. Do I have to run through docker run? I don't mind it it just it seems that it doesn't see my image and starts building its own.

Comment: Yes, you're using a very complex setup. If you look at the compose file for the laradock installation you will find it's actually running multiple services. You'd have to define it for the individual service which ports should be exposed or rather published (which is likely what you want). Your first command is just related to your local firewall so I'm not sure how that'd fit it. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, what works and what isn't.

Comment: Yes that's what I need. So how would I expose it? I mean what kind of line should I add to docker-compose file? The reason for first line is to allow connection from external IP. It works with localhost, internal IP but not with external. If I remember correctly if you would install nginx normally without docker to access it from external IP you have to add iptables rule and it should change from ::::80 to 0.0.0.0:80. If I understand it correctly docker overrwrites iptable rules with its own, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a project which uses a quite complex docker setup. Docker compose is used to start a whole bunch of containers if you look at the [compose file](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) for the project.

Docker itself supports quite a few [different networking modes](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and you might want to check out the docker documentation to learn about it. Especially the [docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/) article can be quite insightful as it explains the default networking behavior.

Have a look at the [nginx configuration](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/913abc54f9edde865a1d6de8a03b38098593ebfb/docker-compose.yml#L224) for that project and check the nginx entry and the env file for the project. You will find that compose file already contains a ports section that, according to the [compose configuration documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), publishes the port for your local network and uses [bridged networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).

What you will need to do is either change the docker network configuration to suite your needs or change your host configuration to provide actual routing (e.g. [1](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world) could be relevant) or, probably easier, run a reverse proxy for your docker application ... you could do this using a docker container.